# JQuerywait until $.get() returns

Tags: jquery

I'm using $.get() in for loop, I need the script to wait for result before continuing with loop.

Below is the code snippet:

```
    for(i=0;i<4;i++) {
      //some code
      $.get(url,function(data1){
        //some code
    });
      //some code 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use async:false

```
$.ajax({
   url:'your url',
   method:'GET'
   async:false,
   success:function(result){
       //some code
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to continue using the shorthand `$.get` you can setup ajax to be synchronous like `jQuery.ajaxSetup({async:false});` before making your request and maybe set it back to true after your code `jQuery.ajaxSetup({async:true});`.